Adding vapor barrier for basement raised floor
I'm going to build a raised wooden floor on my concrete basement floor. I will use 2x4 to make 3.5" frame and cover with 1/2" plywood. My question is, should the visqueen be applied to the concrete under the 2x4's or on top of the 2x4's under the plywood?
Thanks for your help.
